# RestEasy + JacksonJaxbJsonProvider configuring inclusion + annotations

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson

I'm trying to configure jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.2.1 in RestEasy for output empty arrays in Json.

I do them with next code:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonIncludeNullJsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
{
    public JacksonIncludeNullJsonProvider() {
        ObjectMapper mapper =  new ObjectMapper();

        configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, true);
        mapper.getSerializationConfig().withSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);

        super.setMapper(mapper);
    }
}
```

But when I compile project with this class, all JAXB annotations stops working.

As I'm understand, when I register mapper in my own provider, it empties all default settigs from JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.
What configuration must be for JAXB annotations + empty arrays inclusion working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object mapper created in the constructor in your example is not configured to support the JAXB annotations by default. You should either re-use the internal mapper provided by the JacksonJaxJsonProvider super class, or configure your mapper to support the JAXB annotations. Here is a link at [the Jackson JAX-RS wiki.](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQJaxRs)

Here is a question based example of a subclass of JacksonJaxJsonProvider which customizes the internal object mapper in the constructor (not very elegant solution though).

Note that I've inverted the serialization settings from the original question since they don't change the defaults to show the difference in the output from the different providers.

```
public class JacksonProvider {
    public static class JacksonIncludeNullJsonProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
    {
        public JacksonIncludeNullJsonProvider() {
            // must be the first call to initialize the mapper
            configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, false);
            _mapperConfig.getConfiguredMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        }

    }

    public static class Bean {
        @XmlElement(name = "xmlField1")
        public final String field1;
        public final String field2;
        public final String field3 = null;
        public final Map<String, Object> field4 = Collections.emptyMap();

        public Bean(String field1, String field2) {
            this.field1 = field1;
            this.field2 = field2;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JacksonIncludeNullJsonProvider provider = new JacksonIncludeNullJsonProvider();
        JacksonJaxbJsonProvider provider2 = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
        Bean bean = new Bean("a", "b");
        provider.writeTo(bean, Bean.class, null, null, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, null, System.out);
        System.out.println();
        provider2.writeTo(bean, Bean.class, null, null, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, null, System.out);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"xmlField1":"a","field2":"b"}
{"xmlField1":"a","field2":"b","field3":null,"field4":{}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what config must be for outputting null arrays in Java as JSON arrays?

`public final List<Object> field4 = null;`

must be interpreted in:

`"field4":[]`

When I create new unconfigured mapper, as in mys first message, I have this result, but not with using existing mapper.

Comment: You want to output an empty array if the field is null, don't you?

Comment: Yes.

And when I create `ObjectMapper mapper =  new ObjectMapper()` it works, so I think this is configuration issue, at it possible to do that with existing JacksonJaxbJsonProvider's mapper.
But I have no idea, what settings bust be setted.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not able to reproduce this. Not sure that those settings affect the serialization of null arrays. I think that the way to achieve that is to set a special NullSerializer which would write an empty array for all the array types. Have a look at the bottom of [this wiki page](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers)